# Conservar um numero maior numa divisão Python

Tags: python

@Edit
Boa noite, eu estou com um problema neste código abaixo

Nele é realizado duas operações de multiplicação

```
a * h = X 
b * C = Y
```

até ai tudo certo, mas por exemplo, o valor de X é menor que o valor de Y, a conta da errada, ai eu queria saber se é possível dar prioridade ao número maior que é o Y para ser divido pelo menor

```
valor_de_a = input("Insira o valor de A: ")
valor_de_h = input("Insira o valor de H: ")
valor_de_b = input("Insira o valor de B: ")
valor_de_c = input("Insira o valor de C: ")

tempA = float(valor_de_a)
tempH = float(valor_de_h)
tempB = float(valor_de_b)
tempC = float(valor_de_c)

A_H = tempA * tempH
B_C = tempB * tempC

resultadoA = (A_H / B_C)


print("O resultado de a x h é", A_H)
print("O resultado de b x c é", B_C)

print("O resultado final é", resultadoA)
```

Comment: Cleiton, seja bem vindo, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/424044/edit) sua pergunta e coloque seus códigos. Recomendo você a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Acho que as funções min() e max() vão atender seu caso

Answer (score 2):

```
a * h = X 
b * C = Y
```

> até ai tudo certo

Não, não tem nada certo "até aí" - essas expressões podem ser matematicamente válidas, mas são um erro de sintaxe em Python, e não fazem sentido (apesar de serem sintaticamente válidas), na maior parte das linguagens de programação.

Em Python, você coloca uma expressão - matemática, ou programática, mais complexa, do lado *direito* do sinal `=`, e um (ou mais) nomes para o resultado daquela expressão do lado *esquerdo* do sinal de igual. (Só agora vou ler o resto da sua pergunta - já está bem errado até aqui).

Bom - a pergunta segue bem estranha, já que você fala de variáveis "X" e "Y" no seu enunciado, e tem outros nomes no seu programa - mas, suponho que você queria que o resultado final em `resultadoA` sempre seja maior que 1, e se `A_H` for menor que `B_C`, o resultado seja a divisão inversa.

Há algumas formas de fazer isso, mas talvez a mais legível e concisa seja com o operador `if` em linha, usado como um operador ternário.

A forma dele em Python é: `expressao1 if expressao2 else expressao3` - ou seja, se a expressao2 tiver um valor verdadeiro, o resultado da expressão "if" inteiro é a "expressao1" - senão é a "expressao3" - isso é o equivalente em Python a `expressao2 ? expressao1 : expressao3` das linguagens que herdaram a sintaxe de `C` (javascript, Java, c#, ...).

Ou seja, no caso do seu trecho de código acima, é só re-escrever a linha que calcula a expressão que vai em `resultadoA` assim:

```
resultadoA = (A_H / B_C) if A_H >= B_C else (B_C / A_H)
```